# Manually build View Model from Request Data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a page that currently submits via Ajax to a controller method. MVC automatically converts the request data into my View Model type, and that's great.

Now I'm trying to change it so instead of an Ajax post, it makes a SignalR call instead. I want to submit the same data via SignalR (via `$('form').serialize()`), and then parse the data into my view model type.

Example:

```
//controller
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyViewModel vm){
     //vm is automatically created from form data
}

//SignalR Hub
public void MyMethodViaSignalR(string formData){
    //how can I turn formData or Context.Request into a MyViewModel?
}

//Make the SignalR call
myHub($('form').serialize());
```

Comment: I hope you don't have to manually deserialize models with signalR.

Comment: Could you post your view model code?

Comment: That doesn't seem relevant. Just suppose it has normal things like `int`s, dates, strings. I'm hoping for a generic solution that wouldn't require knowing anything about the model.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I found a solution in case you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a generic solution. I put this code in my Base Controller (you could copy it to any one controller as well), and it will build whatever view model you need.

```
    protected class SignalRRequestJSon
    {
        public string H { get; set; }
        public string M { get; set; }
        public List<string> A { get; set; }
        public int I { get; set; }
    }
    public T GetModel<T>(HttpRequest req) where T : class, new()
    {
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignalRRequestJSon>(req["data"]);
        var stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);

        var url = req.UrlReferrer.ToString(); // this value doesn't matter, but needs to be a valid url.
        var queryStringData = obj.A[0];
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", url, queryStringData);
        var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", this.GetType().Name.ToLower().Replace("controller", ""));
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Arbitrary");

        this.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData, this);
        var valueProvider = new QueryStringValueProvider(this.ControllerContext);
        this.ValueProvider = valueProvider;

        var vm = new T();
        UpdateModel(vm, valueProvider);
        return vm;
    }
    public ActionResult Arbitrary<T>(T model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Called like this from my SignalR hub:

```
var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<MyController>();
var vm = controller.GetModel<MyViewModel>(HttpContext.Current.Request);
```